# greedy matching in regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I have the following output:

```
Player name: RON_98
Player name: RON_97
player name: RON_96
```

I need to get the RON part and the digital part after it(for example 98),I used the following regexp: `regexp "(RON)_(\[0-9]*)"`,does this will match the RON_96 of the last line? `"*"` is greedy match, how to match only the first line of the output? do we have something like (RON)_(only match digital)? and can prevent it to match the rest of the line?

Comment: tcl, but can we take it as general?

Comment: Why do you have a `\` in front of `[`?

Comment: @ratzip: It's true that many supports similar syntax, but they may have different way to escape some special character. `\[` looks fishy, so I asked that.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you mean.`(RON)_([0-9]*)` *will* match "RON_98" and then it will stop. There is no digit after the `8`, so the star will do nothing.

Comment: arnep, I can not see the ` in front of [,if there is one, it is a typo

Comment: @Tomalak I do not understand, * is greedy matching right?

Comment: Yes, `*` is greedy. `*?` is the reluctant version.

Comment: @ratzip Right. It matches as many of the preceding atom as possible. The preceding atom is `[0-9]`. This means: The `*` matches as many digits as it can. When there are not more digits on that line, it stops.

Comment: @Tomalak, ok, this means it only match the first line?

Comment: @ratzip: Since it cannot consume anymore character that are in `[0-9]`, it will not match anything from the next line.

Comment: @ratzip Yes, unless you specify the `regexp -all -- "(RON)_(\[0-9]*)"`. Now the command will match `RON_98`, `RON_97` and `RON_96`. In that case it will return 3 and  group 2 will contain `96`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Always put regular expressions in braces in Tcl.

It's not technically necessary (you can use Tcl's language definition to exactly work out what backslashes would be needed to do it any other way) but it's simpler in all cases that you're likely to encounter normally.

The examples below will use this.

---

Regular expressions start matching as soon as they can. Then, under normal (greedy) circumstances they match as much text as they can. Thus, with your sample code and text, the matcher starts trying to match at the `R` on the first line and goes on to consume up to the `8`, at which point it has a match and *stops*. You can verify this by asking `regexp` to report the indices into the string where the match happened instead of the substring that was matched (via the `-indices` option, documented on the manual page).

To get *all* the matches in a string, you have two options:

1. Pass the `-all -inline` options to `regexp` and process the list of results with `foreach`:

   ```
   # Three variables in foreach; one for whole match, one for each substring
   foreach {a b c} [regexp -all -inline {(RON)_([0-9]*)} $thedata] {
       puts "matched '$a', with b=$b and c=$c"
   }
   ```
2. Use the `-indices` option together with the `-start` option, all in a `while` loop, so you step through the string:

   ```
   set idx 0
   while {[regexp -start $idx -indices {(RON)_([0-9]*)} $thedata a b c]} {
       puts "matched at '$a', with subranges '$b' and '$c'"
       set extracted [string range $thedata {*}$c]
       puts "the extracted value is '$extracted'"

       # Advance the place where the next search will start from
       set idx [expr {[lindex $a 1] + 1}]
   }
   ```

I'd normally recommend using the first option; it's much easier to use! Sometimes the second is better as it provides more information and uses less intermediate storage, but it's also much trickier to get right.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you select your stated regex to match multiple lines, it will not match more than the first occurance of what you stated, and this is "RON_98". It will stop after the last digit of the first match. You could even force it to stop after reading a line by using $ at the end of your RegEx (matches an end of line).

For reference, the [0-9] can be written easier as \d (Digit):

```
(RON)_\d*
```

is easier to read.

Comment: I understand it will match the first line. and I learnt something:by using $, how to specify it?

Comment: For instance, using "(RON)_\d*$" would match only, when the literal phrase is at the end of a string. The behaviour changes slightly when using certain flags (i.e. multiline). Do you use any flags to change the standard regex behaviour?